# How do I set up WSGI in Elastic Beanstalk when running AWS Deep Learning Base AMI (Amazon Linux 2)?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my elasticbeanstalk, I have:

```
Platform:
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3
OptionSettings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    RootVolumeSize: "90"
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    ImageId: ami-017ff046baf80c98c
  ...
```

where that ami is https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07NMRZ463 (AWS Deep Learning Base AMI (Amazon Linux 2)).

I have a flask application with `application.py`:

```
....
# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    # application.debug = True
    print('Starting application')
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I load it, my `.platform/hooks/prebuild` runs (I see the logs in `/var/log/eb-hooks.log`). But my application server does not seem to start.

If it matters, my code is in `/var/app/staging` and didn't get moved to `/var/app/current`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you observe any errors in the logs?

Comment: Nope. But I think the Deep Learning AMIs are not setup for WSGI

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: How would I run WSGI? And make sure my app gets moved to current?

Comment: Don't know at the moment. But wouldn't be it easier to install ML libraries on regular EB AMIs? I'm not sure what Deep Learning AMIs have, so maybe it can't be done?

Comment: The deep learning AMIs are for GPU use with CUDA libraries installed

Comment: I see. I won't be able to replicate that in order to test. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more digging around, and I think a one way would be to create your own **custom platform** form EB:

- [Elastic Beanstalk custom platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html)

> You create a platform by providing Elastic Beanstalk with a **Packer** template, and the scripts and files that the template invokes to build an AMI.

However:

> Elastic Beanstalk **doesn't support** custom platforms based on an Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

Not perfect, but maybe this option could be explored further towards using Deep Learning AMI with EB.

Comment: If that’s the case, then I can use Amazon Linux 2 and simply run a prebuild to install CUDA drivers I think. I assume it’ll be somewhat difficult. Alternatively I could use a Ubuntu instance and setup CUDA on that. But then how would I setup WSGI?

Comment: @Shamoon Maybe it would be to install CUDA on current EB instances?